# Material Design Lite: Is Installation on Wordpress possible?

Tags: wordpress, installation, material-design-lite

Random and probably dumb question-can Material-Design-Lite blog template be fully installed on Wordpress? Downloaded the full template from http://www.getmdl.io/templates/blog/index.html and wondering how to use the entire file....

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is possible! I actually was playing around with MDL and integrated it into WordPress. If you are interested you can grab it off GitHub:

https://github.com/braginteractive/MDLWP

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can absolutely make a Wordpress template using MDL. Helping you do that though... is a bit of a big task. Try looking for help around the web on just building Wordpress templates, then when are you working with HTML, use MDL classes and necessary attributes for components.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You'll probably want to do so by creating a new theme. The MDL templates provides static HTML, CSS, and Javascript. Wordpress requires PHP to dynamically add your content. You could approach this from two directions: modifying an existing theme or blank starter-theme to work with the CSS and Javascript, or adding the necessary php to the MDL HTML files (and making them php files).

You could also potentially add the MDL css and javascript through a child theme or plugin to use only select portions of it if you're not looking for a MDL Theme. At a minimum you'll need to add classes to the elements you want to affect, and watch out for potential conflicts.

Not sure of your level of experience, but here are some starting points.

[Wordpress Codex on Theme Development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)

[A tutorial on creating a theme from static html](http://code.tutsplus.com/series/creating-a-wordpress-theme-from-static-html--wp-34294)

[A tutorial on including your css and javascript files](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-include-javascript-and-css-in-your-wordpress-themes-and-plugins--wp-24321)

Answer (score 0):

Write now there are two themes available for free

1. MDLWP - Free Theme and premium plugins available -
   http://mdlwp.com/
2. Realistic - Free theme
       https://wordpress.org/themes/realistic/